# PHPUnit test fails when setting object property within catch block

Tags: php, zend-framework, object, phpunit, try-catch

I'm testing `setSubject` method which sets subject to *(empty subject)* if it is missing.
Zend_Mail throws exception if undeclared property is trying to be accessed (e.g. email subject is missing, better throw some exceptions). More info: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11371
This is what I need to use to be able to test it successfully:

Class

```
protected function setSubject()
{
    # catch exception thrown if non existing $this->message object property is accessed
    try
    {
      $this->subject = $this->defunctTheContent($this->message->getHeaders(), $this->message->subject);
    }
    catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e)
    {
    }
    if( ! $this->subject)
      $this->subject = '(empty subject)';
}
```

Test

```
public function testNoSubject()
{
  $email = new parseEmail(file_get_contents('mail.x'));
  $this->AssertEquals('(empty subject)', $email->subject);
}
```

However, you can see that catch block is empty, if I try this code...

```
protected function setSubject()
{
    try
    {
      $this->subject = $this->defunctTheContent($this->message->getHeaders(), $this->message->subject);
    }
    catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e)
    {
      $this->subject = '(empty subject)';
    }
}
```

Test fails with message:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) Email_ParseTest::testNoSubject
>   InvalidArgumentException: subject is required

It complains that $this->subject is not set (or similar).

Some more info:

- PHP 5.4.8
- Zend Framework 1.9.5
- PHPUnit 3.6.12
- `subject` is defined as empty string (`""`)

I've tested second method "by hand", and it is working as expected (subject is set within catch block). I don't have much experience with PHPUnit so this might be `E_PEBKAC` easily.

Comment: Could you try var_dump("foo"); in catch block to see if control goes to catch block ever? If it doesn’t, it won’t most likely catch correct exception.

Answer (score 3):

Unless i'm misunderstanding your question, you're attempting to test a protected method... you can't do that this way.  Protected and private methods are suppose to be tested by testing the public methods that use them.

If you're using PHP 5.3.2+ with PHPUnit, you can test your private and protected methods directly by using reflection to set them to be public prior to running your tests, however, as I've mentioned, you're suppose to test public methods.

But if you want to use reflection, here's a generic example:

```
protected static function getMethod($name) {
  $class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
  $method = $class->getMethod($name);
  $method->setAccessible(true);
  return $method;
}

public function testFoo() {
  $foo = self::getMethod('foo');
  $obj = new MyClass();
  $foo->invokeArgs($obj, array(...));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for uber late reply, I'm not testing protected method directly, it's being called from constructor (it was the current codebase). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're catching the wrong exception: Zend_Mail seems to throw an `InvalidArgumentException`, while you're catching a `Zend_Mail_Exception`.

Try the following code:

```php
protected function setSubject()
{
    # catch exception thrown if non existing $this->message object property is accessed
    try {
        $this->subject = $this->defunctTheContent($this->message->getHeaders(), $this->message->subject);
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $this->subject = '(empty subject)';
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Reading again your question, I'd say that `Zend_Mail_Exception` is never thrown.
If you remove the `try`/`catch` from the first block of code, I'd bet it will work as well:

```php
protected function setSubject()
{
    $this->subject = $this->defunctTheContent($this->message->getHeaders(), $this->message->subject);
    if (! $this->subject) {
        $this->subject = '(empty subject)';
    }
}
```

[Line 396](https://github.com/dmelo/Zend-1.11/blob/master/Mail/Part.php#L396) refers to a non-existing header, but it looks like it's not triggered even when `$this->subject` is empty (the exception class & message do not match your test result). I suspect that this header has been set before, in Zend or somewhere else, to an empty value.

That would explain why, in the second case, `$this->subject` is never set (the `catch` code is never executed). The `InvalidArgumentException` is probably thrown by the `parseEmail` class, which detects that `subject` is not set.

The second block, however, does unconditionally check for `! $this->subject`, and sets it accordingly. So the test passes.

To summarize:

- `Zend_Mail_Exception` is never thrown
- `InvalidArgumentException` is thrown in `parseEmail`

Comment: I'm not sure about that: https://github.com/dmelo/Zend-1.11/blob/master/Mail/Part.php#L396, either way, this code works fine when used outside of unit tests. Thanks.

Comment: Negative for `InvalidArgumentException` or `Exception`.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your problem then! See my updated answer.

Comment: `$this->message` is `Zend_Mail` object, which in fact throws `Zend_Mail_Exception` if you try to access some header (object property) which doesn't exist e.g. `subject`. I added try/catch because uncaught exception caused fatal error, but for me, subject is optional. I understand what are you saying, however, it is still not working as expected. Thanks. P.S. Subject is an empty string `private $subject = ""`.

Comment: Have you tried the code in my updated answer? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: yes I am getting uncaught exception (Zend_Mail_Exception) error, that is the reason I introduced try/catch, originally, code was like the one you posted...

Comment: I think there's an information missing in here. At least, with what you provided, I can't see a logical explanation right now.

Comment: I'm not sure what is missing, but I can't see one too. You'll notice I don't ask much, but when I do...

Comment: Sorry I can't help! Do let me know if you find the solution.